# What is the average time against memory size?

Tags: memory, memtest

I have 32GB memory being 2 x 8GB a KIT and the other 2 x 8GB single memories(as in not brought as a KIT) and together they make a quad channel, they are all "1600 10 10 10 30" same model and everything.

However running memtest86 to make sure they are all OK it takes an awfully long time and I was wondering:

- What are the average time it takes to run memtest/GB a memory have?
- Also should a PASS take longer than the previous PASS?

I am using memtest86 not the plus version if that matters and the motherboard/CPU is ASRock Extreme 4 x79 and i7 3930K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you have all the modules from the same manufacturer and all are having the same specs,  it doesn't matter if they came in a kit or not. They are going to work in multichannel mode.

Memtest in theory can go on and on, testing various unique cases that a memory can have, especially larger ram modules are extensivly tested. It reports a fail only In the event that a unique and random test reports as an error. Otherwise the status remains as a pass.

So let the test run till your hearts content for about 30 minutes, if it still shows a pass then all is good.

Comment: The first pass came after 2 hours the 2nd pass never came after 4 hours, that's why I would like to know if there is an average/GB that I can take into account after each pass.

Comment: There is no such fixed value. Memtest usually tries to find for that one instance when memory can fail, so this can be acheived some times in 5 minutes or 5 hours regardless of how many gb there is. Two hours is fine, your ram chips have been tested rigorously.